# visual studio 2015 - debug node.js and browser at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have created a node.js project in visual studio 2015, which starts the web browser (microsoft edge) on launch. For the current moment, I can only debug my node.js code. Is there any way to be able to debug my whole app end-to-end at the same time? That is, to be able to put break points both in my server-side node.js code and my client side's js code. I know it is possible to achieve it in webstorm (with chrome)... so I wonder if I can have this same experience in visual studio.

Thanks!